# AngularJS : Guidance to implement a factory, service, directive or something else

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I'm very new to angularjs and need some advice about the angular way to implement something very simple. In my $scope I need to set some field defaults, and these defaults are needed multiple times in my controller.

I want to be able to refactor these defaults out to a common place, to thin out the controller and allow for code reuse,  but not sure if this should be a factory, directive or service.

Heres an example of the defaults:

```
$scope.skills = [{
  description: '',
  years: "1",
  level: "0",
  years_values: [
    { id: "1", description: "1" },
    { id: "2", description: "2" },
    { id: "3", description: "3+" }],
  level_values: [
    { id: "0", description: "Starter"},
    { id: "1", description: "Intermediate"},
    { id: "2", description: "Advanced"} ]
}]
```

Here's an example of where I'd like to call the "new function":

```
skillSuccess = (resp)->
  Loader.hide();
  $rootScope.current_user = resp;
  #TODO replace this repetition
  $scope.skills = [{
    description: '',
    .... etc
```

My questions are:

1. Should I use a factory/directive/service, (or something else) for
   this refactoring?
2. How do I ensure that the function gets called
   initially so that the default values are available for the fields
   when the page loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I use a factory/directive/service, (or something else) for this refactoring?

A controller should be used to set the scope, but the default values should be stored as a constant and returned by a factory. A factory pattern is preferred here because it is a singleton.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('skillsFactory', function (defaultSkills) {
        var service = {};

        service.getDefaults = function () {
            return defaultSkills;
        };

        return service;
    })
    .constant('defaultSkills', [{
        description: '',
        years: "1",
        level: "0",
        years_values: [{
            id: "1",
            description: "1"
        }, {
            id: "2",
            description: "2"
        }, {
            id: "3",
            description: "3+"
        }],
        level_values: [{
            id: "0",
            description: "Starter"
         }, {
            id: "1",
            description: "Intermediate"
        }, {
            id: "2",
            description: "Advanced"
        }]
    }]);
```

> How do I ensure that the function gets called initially so that the default values are available for the fields when the page loads?

In your controller, call `$scope.skills = skillsFactory.getDefaults();`

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('skillsCtrl', function ($scope, skillsFactory) {
        $scope.skills = skillsFactory.getDefaults();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use a factory/directive/service, (or something else) for this
>   refactoring?

I'd suggest you to create a `constant` because looks like you have `defaults` data which has initially has some value and that will going to be change by the user from the front-end. So you could place that in angular constant, then that constant will be accessed by the factory/service. And Factory/service will do the needful manipulation from its function. To make available constant in your service/factory you need to inject constant name in your service.

By looking at your current requirement you shouldn't be take consideration of `directive` component.

**Constant**

```
app.constant('defaults', [{
  description: '',
  years: "1",
  level: "0",
  years_values: [
    { id: "1", description: "1" },
    { id: "2", description: "2" },
    { id: "3", description: "3+" }],
  level_values: [
    { id: "0", description: "Starter"},
    { id: "1", description: "Intermediate"},
    { id: "2", description: "Advanced"} ]
}]);
```

**Service**

```
app.service('dataService', function(defaults){
   var dataService = this;
   dataService.defaults = defaults; 
   dataService.defaults = angular.copy(defaults) //will return same copy every-time
   dataService.getDefaults = function(){
     return dataService.defaults; 
   }
   //other method will lie here
})
```

> How do I ensure that the function gets called initially so that the default values are available for the fields when the page loads?

You could simply get that defaults by consuming `getDefaults` method of your service, then stored that retrieved defaults and use those for manipulation.
If you want the defaults copy to instantiated every-time then use `angular.copy(defaults)` which will give you the copy of defaults.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, dataService){
   $scope.defaults = dataService.getDefaults(); //this will have defaults
   //...other stuff here...
});
```

Comment: @downoter may I know the reason behind downvote? please keep comment so that I can improve myself..

Comment: Your answer was good and worthy of acceptance imo, but I had to give it to preston-van-loon as he succintly explained in one line what I needed to do. I also scored some design patterns from him for free. :)

Comment: @juddey oh.. `naming convention !== design patterns ` .. may I know what design pattern you learnt from the above answer? Actually the thing is he has same code as that of mine only changed the variable names..you could check the history of an answer..Also he had downvoted mine answer for no reason..

Comment: I'm sorry you feel this way. In reality I had to choose between the two answers (both of which were very good). If I could have given two accepts, I would have.